# Configure Python 2.7.3 interpreter in aptana studio?

Tags: software-installation

I have installed Aptana studio on Ubuntu and i don't know when configuring a new python interpreter what folder/file to choose.

I have python 2.7.3 already installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to: `Window` menu > `Preferences`. On the left side of `Preferences`, you will see `PyDev` options, click to expand. Under `PyDev`, look for `Interpreter - Python` and click to view the preferences. Now you will see on the right a `New` option, windows will popup, and just enter the command from the screenshot below. [image][image]